# PHP - .htaccess Re-Write for external server connections

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have multiple servers and a main server hosting my API.

[Server 1] <---> [API Server] 
[Server 2] <---> [API Server]

I am having a bit of struggle actually sending the `curl` request to the API server and am unsure if its possible from external servers. I read up an article about using a redirect so the server acts like its internal (CORS).

The URL needed is (where the API file is located):

```
$this->url = "http://www.example.com/API/RequestsDJ/API/RequestsHandler.php";
```

However, I am struggling with writing the .htaccess file, so far I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule API/RequestsDJ/(.*)$ API/RequestsDJ/API/RequestsHandler.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The idea here is to convert the URL to:

```
$this->url = "http://www.example.com/API/RequestsDJ";
```

Which is then, through the CORS method, redirected as an internal request which then runs the functions inside the: `API/RequestsDJ/API/RequestsHandler.php` file. (I am not sure also if this will carry the POST data with it but for now, its just for testing).

Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks in advance, I suck at .htaccess files (the API doesn't support any GET requests, so any `?example=` is not needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to change the rexep rule on RewriteRule from this:

```
RewriteRule API/RequestsDJ/(.*)$ API/RequestsDJ/API/RequestsHandler.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

To this:

```
 RewriteRule ^API/RequestsDJ/(.*)$ API/RequestsDJ/API/RequestsHandler.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

You probably don't need the `QSA flag` either as you take all parameters in using POST. Query params won't be required.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to send a `curl` request to another domain/server. However, security issues limitate this. So I came across a CORS method where you add a redirect so that external request becomes internal therefore allowing the request to continue. At the moment, I am unsure whether it will let me pick up the response or POST but for the time being, I just need to get the request through. I'll try this now however :D Thanks!

Comment: This actually got the `POST` data through as well as the response. Perfect!